# Can Sway be used as a full screen compositor

Tags: linux, wayland, window-management, sway

I never like the "desktop" metaphor, so when Wayland rolled around I switched to Sway thinking that a tiling compositor was what I wanted. But after using Sway for a few months I realized that I didn't really want a tiling compositor either. It is true that *sometimes* I like to have two applications side-by-side, but most of the time I want to have multiple fullscreen application and Alt-Tab between them. Furthermore, I almost never want to have 3 or 4 applications side by side, which is what Sway does if you keep opening applications--it keeps making vertical "tiles" so the applications become narrow strips arranged vertically on the screen.

Is there a way to configure Sway to do what I want:

(A) open new applications full screen by default
(B) Alt-Tab to move between applications
(C) open an application side-by-side on those occasions when needed

Comment: since it is supposed to be mostly i3 compatible, why not just use one workspace per application. `bindsym $mod+Tab workspace next` etc.

Comment: @meuh Because when you open a new application it does open a new workspace. So, I would have to resort to clumsy workarounds. Also, many actions cause an application to be automatically opened. For example, if you open a PDF in a browser, or open an image in a file manager. None of these actions open a new workspace.